# Ubuntu 23.04 freeze at login screen after fn lock

Tags: login, freeze, gdm, wayland, lock

I have basically clean install of latest Ubuntu 23.04 on my Lattitude laptop (no nvidia or proprietary drivers)
And after a few days, it suddenly started to freeze right at login screen.
Have to go to recovery to restart gdm - `systemctl restart gdm.service` to be able to boot to login screen with no wayland boot option (x11 only) and then I am able to login.
When I restart and try to login again, it freezes again.
This issue seems to have happened after I hit the the fn-lock key on my keyboard strangely.
Maybe the wayland session remembers the function lock being on and that somehow freezes it? Not sure how to check for that tho or how to disable it.